# Calling an alias in a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have the following code. I am attempting to change the name server and then reference the command nslookup to use that name server but it doesn't work i.e. it returns the error that `nslook` does not exist.

```
@ECHO OFF
@DOSKEY NSLOOK=NSLOOKUP $* 1.2.3.4
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%j in (
  'nslook %%i ^| find "Name:"'
) do @echo %%j >> dns.txt 2>> error.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the DosKey?... in batch they have their own macro system: SET VAR= and %VAR%

```
set nslook=nslookup
for /F %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%j in ('%nslook% %%i  2^>^>error.txt ^| find "Name:"') do (
        echo %%j >> dns.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but it doesn't tell me the server names that encountered the error. All i get in the error file `Request to 1.2.3.4 timed-out`

Comment: Hm... so, wasn't that supposed to be like that? When I tested it, in servers.txt I've put 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 plus some fakes, these are all I know from the top of my head. The two are good, they landed in dns.txt as name resolved addresses, the fakes landed in error.txt. Or did you prefer the errors to be printed? In that case remove  2^>^>error.txt